# Join with multiple tables and GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three main tables: `books`, `authors`, `publishers` and two connecting tables: `authors_on_books` & `books_on_publishers`.

I'm trying to get all the data using the following query:

```
select books.*, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(authors.id) as author_id, GROUP_CONCAT(authors.name) as author_name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(publishers.id) as publisher_id, GROUP_CONCAT(publishers.name) as publisher_name

        from books
        join authors_on_books on authors_on_books.book_id = books.id
        join authors on authors_on_books.author_id = authors.id
        join books_on_publishers on books_on_publishers.book_id = books.id
        join publishers on books_on_publishers.publisher_id = publishers.id
        group by books.id
```

The result I'm getting is:

```
[id] => 1
[title] => Title 1
[description] => This is a book
[year_published] => 1999
[isbn] => 11111111
[author_id] => 1,1,2,2,3,3
[author_name] => author 1,author 1,author 2,author 2,author 3,author 3
[publisher_id] => 1,1,1,1,1,1
[publisher_name] => publisher 1,publisher 1,publisher 1,publisher 1,publisher 1,publisher 1
```

But the desired outcome is:

```
[id] => 1
[title] => Title 1
[description] => This is a book
[year_published] => 1999
[isbn] => 11111111
[author_id] => 1,2,3
[author_name] => author 1,author 2,author 3
[publisher_id] => 1,2
[publisher_name] => publisher 1,publisher 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use distinct in group_concat

```
  select books.*, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct uthors.id) as author_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct authors.name) as author_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct publishers.id) as publisher_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct publishers.name) as publisher_name

    from books
    join authors_on_books on authors_on_books.book_id = books.id
    join authors on authors_on_books.author_id = authors.id
    join books_on_publishers on books_on_publishers.book_id = books.id
    join publishers on books_on_publishers.book_id = publishers.id
    group by books.id
```

But remember that group_concat(distinct...) have a certain impact on performance..

and as  suggested  by gordon linoff you could use left join for ensure that get all books

```
  select books.*, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct uthors.id) as author_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct authors.name) as author_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct publishers.id) as publisher_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(distinct publishers.name) as publisher_name

    from books
    left join authors_on_books on authors_on_books.book_id = books.id
    left join authors on authors_on_books.author_id = authors.id
    left join books_on_publishers on books_on_publishers.book_id = books.id
    left join publishers on books_on_publishers.book_id = publishers.id
    group by books.id
```

Comment: This is a fine solution, but I should note two things.  First, you may want to use `left join`s to ensure that you get all books, even those with no authors or publishers in the database (if that is possible).  Second, I note that pre-aggregating the authors and publishers may result in better performance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  thanks  .. correct  .. answer  updated  with your suggestion too

Comment: How can I fix the answer to display books with a specific author (together with co-authors)?